# How to disable a windows schedule task in Windows 10 using the utility schtasks?

Tags: windows, scheduled-tasks

How can I disable a schedule task in Windows 10? They suggested me to use `/disable` but apparently and that option is already gone in Windows 10 and was available in the previous versions of Windows.

```
>schtasks  /?

SCHTASKS /parameter [arguments]

Description:
    Enables an administrator to create, delete, query, change, run and
    end scheduled tasks on a local or remote system.

Parameter List:
    /Create         Creates a new scheduled task.

    /Delete         Deletes the scheduled task(s).

    /Query          Displays all scheduled tasks.

    /Change         Changes the properties of scheduled task.

    /Run            Runs the scheduled task on demand.

    /End            Stops the currently running scheduled task.

    /ShowSid        Shows the security identifier corresponding to a scheduled task name.

    /?              Displays this help message.

Examples:
    SCHTASKS
    SCHTASKS /?
    SCHTASKS /Run /?
    SCHTASKS /End /?
    SCHTASKS /Create /?
    SCHTASKS /Delete /?
    SCHTASKS /Query  /?
    SCHTASKS /Change /?
    SCHTASKS /ShowSid /?
```

I doubt `delete` will actually disable it.

How can I do that then?

UPDATE:

I need to do this **only** by the utility `schtasks`

Comment: Have you tried the (seemingly) deprecated `/disable` switch?

Comment: "They suggested me to use /disable"  Who's "They"?  "that option is gone in Windows 10 and was available in the previous versions of Windows." Schtasks in Windows 10 works exactly the same as it did in 7 and 8 (as far as `/disable` is concerned anyway), so I'm not sure who gave you the info about how to use the `/disable` switch, but they're wrong -- see Doenoe's answer for proper usage (on all Windows versions).

Comment: I was wondering by the way why you only want to use schtasks.exe instead of powershell?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Powershell!

```
Disable-ScheduledTask -TaskName "Adobe Flash Player Update"



TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\                                              Adobe Flash Player Updater        Disabled
```

EDIT:

with the use schtasks.exe:

```
schtasks.exe /change /tn "Adobe Flash Player Updater" /disable

SUCCESS: The parameters of scheduled task "Adobe Flash Player Updater" have been changed.
```

Comment: i've updated my question.

Comment: editted my answer. ;)

Comment: I've run the command to disable a task and it said "ERROR: The specified task name "....." does not exist in the system." I took its name from ComputerManagement -> Task Scheduler

Answer (score 4):

GUI:

1. Open the "Task Scheduler"
2. Open "Task Scheduler Library" -> "Microsoft" -> "Windows", "Application Experience".
3. Disable "Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser" with a right-click choice.

CMD:

```
schtasks /Change /Disable /TN "Microsoft\Windows\Application Experience\Microsoft Compatibility Appraiser"
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use the Task Scheduler MMC snap-in. You can type "Task Scheduler" in the Cortana search box or run mmc.exe and add the snap-in manually. Once you get the GUI, just right-click on the task and choose "disable" - it's still there, just hidden :) I'm not sure why the command line has changed - weird...